# Output of this strange loop related to matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, pseudocode

Let us consider the following pseudocode:

```
int n=n;
int A[][]
scanf(A[][],%d);
for i=1:n;i++
{
  x=A[i][i]
  for j=1:n;j++
  {
    if x<A[i][j]
      a=x;
    x=A[i][j];
    A[i][i]=x;
    A[i][j]=a;
    return A[][]
```

I am fumbling on this pseudo code.the question, I think is just that the diagonal entries are compared and exchanged for the greatest entries. But, will the output depend on the entries of the matrix or will be independent of it is my main question. Specifically, is there any general formula for the output?  Is it dependent on the type of matrix `A` I think it should some power of A. Any hints? Thanks beforehand.

Comment: What prevents you from replacing the pseudo code with actual C code?

Comment: Oh, marking this "pseudo code" with "c" tag was a kind of torture ?)

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann my lack of knowlege of C

Comment: @grapes is there any tag for pseudo code?

Comment: why the downvote? Is the question dumb or already answered?

Comment: I think, even in pseudo code `int A[][]=A;` would be nonsense.

Comment: @wildplasser sorry, so just that I want a variable to hold the matrix which I could call later for input

Comment: I guess you got downvoted because someone felt: "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful (click again to undo)"

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann where is the lack of clarity? Anybody could ask for more clarification. Is the sense of the question clear, I mean does nobody get the jist of question?

Comment: Look at all to comments your question generated. People checking new questions to see whether they can help, stop and wonder what you are asking and stopping again to add a comment. I do not think this is an effective way of dealing with other peoples time.

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann ok, quite somewhat edited, is the question clear now?

Comment: I am not the one to judge (and I don't particularly care).

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann ok, the question, I think is just that the diagnoal entries are compared and exchanged for the greatest entries. But, will the output depend on the entries of the matrix or will be independent of it is my main question. Specifically, is there any general formula for the output?

Comment: Yes, there is a [pseudocode] tag

Comment: @grapes thanks, edited. Please check now.

Answer (score 1):

You could just write your code on any language you love.

```
n = 3
A = [[1,2,3], [3,5,6], [7,8,9]]

for i in range(n):
  x=A[i][i]
  for j in range(n):
    a = None
    if x < A[i][j]:
      a = x
    x=A[i][j]
    A[i][i]=x
    A[i][j]=a

print (A)
```

Gives you:

```
[[3, 1, 2], [None, 6, 3], [None, 7, None]]
```

> But, will the output depend on the entries of the matrix or will be
>   independent of it is my main question.

Ofc it depends. Your can see the initial data in the output. That means output depends on data.

> Specifically, is there any general formula for the output?

I believe NO, but I cant mathematically prove. Just look at `Nones` appear in output. I hardly imagine such formula.

> Is it dependent on the type of matrix A I think it should some power
>   of A.

What is 'type of matrix' ?

Comment: ok, thanks. But what about any geneal matrix? Is there any way of deciding beforehand?